# How to get the height and width of an image in Angular 2(or above) from input tag before uploading it to the server without jQuery?

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I checked various sources but most of the solutions are in jQuery. I want the solution in Typescript if possible.

HTML -

`<input #coverFilesInput class="file-input" type="file"(change)="onChange($event)"....>`

Typescript -

```
onChange($event) { let img = event.target.files[0]; // and then I need code to validate image size }
```

Is there a solution or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: check my answer if you want to validate the width/height after selecting the image.

Comment: check the demo link  to validate it before posting to server

Answer (score 11):

You can use the combination of `@ViewChild and ElementRef` to access the file upload control and clear it's value after every upload otherwise the `(change)` event would not fire.

And then you can use `FileReader()` to read the file into an `Image` object and get the width and height from it.

Here is the code below -

**HTML template**

```
<input type="file" #coverFilesInput (change)="onChange($event)" class="file-input"  />
    Upload Percent: {{percentDone}}% <br />

    <ng-container *ngIf="uploadSuccess">
      Upload Successful of file with size : {{size}} bytes <br>
      The image height is : {{height}} <br>
      The image width is : {{width}} <br>
    </ng-container>
```

**The onChange method**

```
onChange(evt:any){
   this.percentDone = 100;
   this.uploadSuccess = true;
   let image:any = evt.target.files[0];
   this.size = image.size;
   let fr = new FileReader();
   fr.onload = () => { // when file has loaded
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
        this.width = img.width;
        this.height = img.height;
    };

    img.src = fr.result; // The data URL 
};

  fr.readAsDataURL(image);
   this.imgType.nativeElement.value = ""; // clear the value after upload
  }
```

**complete code app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION ,ViewChild,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpEventType} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    Version = {{version.full}} <br/>
    <input type="file" #coverFilesInput (change)="onChange($event)" class="file-input"  />
    Upload Percent: {{percentDone}}% <br />

    <ng-container *ngIf="uploadSuccess">
      Upload Successful of file with size : {{size}} bytes <br>
      The image height is : {{height}} <br>
      The image width is : {{width}} <br>
    </ng-container> 
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  percentDone: number;
  uploadSuccess: boolean;
  size:any;
  width:number;
  height:number;

  @ViewChild('coverFilesInput') imgType:ElementRef;

  constructor(
    ) { }

  version = VERSION

  onChange(evt:any){
   this.percentDone = 100;
   this.uploadSuccess = true;
   let image:any = evt.target.files[0];
   this.size = image.size;
   let fr = new FileReader();
   fr.onload = () => { // when file has loaded
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = () => {
        this.width = img.width;
        this.height = img.height;
    };

    img.src = fr.result; // This is the data URL 
   };

  fr.readAsDataURL(image);
   this.imgType.nativeElement.value = "";
  }  
}
```

Here is a working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-hnik7q

**Edit :** you can also use `[(ngModel)]="selectedFile"` to access the input file control and clear it's value after the validation and upload is done without using `@ViewChild` and `ElementRef` like below -

```
<input type="file" #coverFilesInput (change)="onChange($event)" class="file-input"  [(ngModel)]="selectedFile"/>
```

and in component class -

```
export class AppComponent {
  percentDone: number;
  uploadSuccess: boolean;
  size:any;
  width:number;
  height:number;
  selectedFile:any; // declare the property

  constructor(
    ) { }

  version = VERSION

  onChange(evt:any){
   this.percentDone = 100;
   this.uploadSuccess = true;
   let image:any = evt.target.files[0];
   this.size = image.size;
   let fr = new FileReader();
   fr.onload = () => { // when file has loaded
    var img = new Image();    
    img.onload = () => {
        this.width = img.width;
        this.height = img.height;
    };    
    img.src = fr.result; // This is the data URL 
};    
  fr.readAsDataURL(image);
  this.selectedFile = ""; // clear the file here
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this way, it's work for me!!

```
// in your .html file
<input type="file" class="form-control"
            accept="image/*" 
            (change)="onChange($event)">    

// in your .ts file
onChange(fileInput: any) {
    const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const Img = new Image();

    const filesToUpload = (fileInput.target.files);
    Img.src = URL.createObjectURL(filesToUpload[0]);

    Img.onload = (e: any) => {
      const height = e.path[0].height;
      const width = e.path[0].width;

      console.log(height,width);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **ElementRef**.

First you need to mark your dom element `#myImage`

Then in your component class you can target the dom element with **ViewChild**

`ViewChild('myImage')
  myImage: ElementRef;`

Once the view is loaded you can extract the image details

`ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.myImage.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
console.log(this.myImage.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
  }`

Since you are just extracting information about the dom element, the security risk is low. I would advise you not to modify dom elements using this method.