# How to access to element "path" in Event with angular

Tags: angular

for my example i took an image in the template:

```
<img class="cImg" (load)="onChange($event)" src="../../../assets/img/noob.jpg">
```

I would like to access to the element "path" from an even with angular
I've read some other post about it, like:
[Angular - How do I parse the objects in inside event.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879324/angular-how-do-i-parse-the-objects-in-inside-event-path)

or

[How to get the height and width of an image in Angular 2(or above) from input tag before uploading it to the server without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566385/how-to-get-the-height-and-width-of-an-image-in-angular-2or-above-from-input-ta/50567853)

but none of this on work for me.

**Event structure:**

[image]

There is the code with the error I get with someway I've tried to use to get access to an element of the element "path"

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

I tried also to get it by the target, base on what I've read, with no success

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the type:

```
const paths = (event as any).path as HTMLElement[];
```

When you have the wanted item, if you want to get some style, you can achieve that doing so:

```
const style = this.windowRef.getComputedStyle(elem); // or window.getComputedStyle(elem)
```

Bu normaly, you can fetch `clientHeight` for example directly with `elem.clientHeight`.

This works: `(event as any).path[0].clientHeight`

Comment: Thanks you! The problem is I can't get other elements inside of "paths", like, example clientHeight. I thought by getting the path I could go under with ```forEach``` or ```path[0].clientHeight``` to get the size. but it doesn't work :(

Comment: There is something strange, if I do ```path[0].clientHeight``` I get 0 and in reality if I watch ```path[0]``` I see in the element ```clientHeight``` 400..... Maybe I'm drunk :D

Comment: I don't understand. Sometime it works, sometime not.... Do you have an idea where it cans come from ?

Comment: No, sorry, I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reach path property just use:

```
onChange($event) {
    console.log($event.path);
}
```